# What is the difference between JS games and HTML5 canvas games?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to learn internet games design. When I looked for that on the internet I was confused between "JS" and "HTML5" games.
Are they the same? and if they are not what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms *JS games* and *HTML5 games* overlap.

All HTML5 games are also JS games. You can't make much of a game without JavaScript.

Some JS games are HTML5 games. That would generally mean that they use some new features that were not available before HTML5. Some games are also put in the category JS games even if they use HTML5 features.

Answer (score 2):

They are nearly the same,

Canvas is an HTML element that you can use, which requires JS to run.
Other options would be using SVG or HTML DOM for the view elements.

So Canvas is not the same as JS games but a tool which you can use in your JS games ;).